# Angular binding deosn't update view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the below scenario An external function is updating the `$scope.contacts`, before exiting the function I call the `$scope.$apply()`, since the scope is updated outside AngularJS context. But it still doesn't render the view for me.

P.S. In debugging I can see $scope.contacts properly filled with the elements.

I am quite new to AngularJS, is that anything I am missing or not doing properly?

```
    module.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
        $scope.contacts = []; 
        ...
        $scope.load = function () {
           ...
           external function(){
                    ...
                for(){
                   var contact = {
                   id: id.slice(id.length-1),
                   Name: fullname,
                   Email: email,
                   Phone: phone 
                   };

                   $scope.contacts.push(contact);
                }

                $scope.$apply();
            }

        }
  });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better if you provide js fiddler or Plnkr.co demo

Comment: $scope.$apply(function(){

Comment: @NareshKumar I've tried that, It gives exactly the same result